# Laravel - update table1 column with table2 column

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to use this kind of query in a migration script.

```
update table1, table2 set table1.column = table2.another_column where table1.id=table2.foreign_id
```

How to do this the laravel/eloquent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
DB::table('table1')
    ->join('table2', 'table1.id', 'table2.foreign_id')
    ->update(['table1.column' => DB::raw('table2.another_column')]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Doesn't the join clause also need an operator?

Comment: Do you have the same problem? What doesn't work? You can omit the operator and Laravel will use `=` by default.